# change the mic sensitivity from winapi

Tags: c, winapi, audio

how can I change the mic sensitivity like I can do it from control panel using?, I want to do it through winapi and the code must be compatible with windows 7 + windowXp both 32bit and 64bit ..

Comment: Did you search with Google before asking here?

Comment: yes, if u have any link I would be thankful

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1504/A-simple-record-and-playback-volume-control-class) will help you.